# Bad configuration on Spring-mvc Maven Hibernate, can't access http no mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

i'm having some issues. I'm building an application with Spring Tool Suit, consist of SpringMVC Maven and Hibernate. I think i have all my coding ok or close to be good despite i'm noob with spring.

Here i put 2 screens of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzhOd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRId.png

Here i put what i think the files that are involved on the issue

aplication-config.mxl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


         <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.service"/>

</beans>
```

GeneralController.java:

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import form.Egg;
import service.EggService;

@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/ChickenTest/**")
public class GeneralController {

    @Autowired
    EggService eggService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/index")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        return mav;
    }

    //Index of Egg webpage
    @RequestMapping(value="/Egg/indexEgg")
    public ModelAndView indexEgg(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        return mav;
    }

    //Action of adding an Egg
    @RequestMapping(value="/Egg/addEgg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addEgg(@ModelAttribute Egg egg){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/index");

        Egg eggAux = egg;
        eggService.addEgg(eggAux);

        return mav;
    }

    //View list of eggs
    @RequestMapping(value="/Egg/viewEggs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView viewEggs(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/index");

        mav.getModelMap().addAttribute("eggList", eggService.viewEggs());

        return null;
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/Chicken/indexChicken")
    ModelAndView indexChicken(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Farm/indexFarm")
    ModelAndView indexFarm(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        return mav;
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>ChickenTest</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

mvc-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


         <context:component-scan
            base-package="org.springframework.samples.web"/>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is what the console outputs when i try to enter one of my jsp:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ChickenTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ ChickenTest >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ChickenTest ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ ChickenTest ---
[INFO] Compiling 16 source files to C:\Java\workspace2\ChickenTest\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ ChickenTest <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ ChickenTest ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/ChickenTest
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\Java\workspace2\ChickenTest\target\tomcat
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Nov 08 00:31:45 ART 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@767ae5: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 245 ms
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Nov 08 00:31:45 ART 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:45 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@132299b: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@767ae5
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:46 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 384 ms
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:46 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 08, 2013 12:31:46 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Finally this is what the explorer shows when i try to enter this url http:// localhost:8080/ChickenTest/index.jsp

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ChickenTest/index.jsp

type Status report

message /ChickenTest/index.jsp

description The requested resource (/ChickenTest/index.jsp) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

Thanks for reading! i will be in touch if you need something more!

---

update 1:

Hi there again, i applied this solution:

```
First, your @Controller class is in

package controller;
so your DispatcherServlet config needs to have a component-scan on that package. So change yours to

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
So that the <mvc:annotation-driven> gets applied and your @Controller class is added as a handler.

Now even if you do this, you still don't seem to have a handler method for the path

/ChickenTest/index.jsp
You'll want to either add a <welcome-file> to your web.xml and an index.jsp file in your /webapps folder or add a @RequestMapping handler method that can handler /index.jsp.
```

but now the console tells me that the @Autowire on GeneralController.class is not working.

This is my new error:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'generalController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.chicken.service.EggService com.chicken.controller.GeneralController.eggService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.chicken.service.EggService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your `@Controller` class is in

```
package controller;
```

so your `DispatcherServlet` config needs to have a `component-scan` on that package. So change yours to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
```

So that the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` gets applied and your `@Controller` class is added as a handler.

Now even if you do this, you still don't seem to have a handler method for the path

```
/ChickenTest/index.jsp
```

You'll want to either add a `<welcome-file>` to your web.xml and an `index.jsp` file in your `/webapps` folder or add a `@RequestMapping` handler method that can handler `/index.jsp`.

---

The Exception you now get is (broken down)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'generalController': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: com.chicken.service.EggService com.chicken.controller.GeneralController.eggService; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.chicken.service.EggService] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So, the component scan couldn't create a bean for `GeneralController` because the Spring context could not find an `EggService` bean which it needs to inject into it. The only possible reason for this is that **there is no `EggService` bean in your context.** Either you haven't declared in as a `<bean>` or your `component-scan` isn't scanning the package where your `EggService` class is declared as a `@Component`.

Comment: I think i create the bean, but i don't know why it isn't worcking